# codeigniter non latin characters ajax call

Tags: php, codeigniter, character, non-latin

I have a textarea and a button where i send the text via ajax to the database to post it.

However when i post non-latin characters... it wont get them and it returns blank... if the text is in latin characters it works fine...

my js code

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: www+"controller/postText",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    input       : input.val(),
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    return data;
                }
            });
```

my php code

```
public function postText(){

    $input = isset($_POST["input"]) ? trim($_POST["input"]) : "";

    echo $input;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing your input using `$this->input->post('input')`

Also, trim might cause trouble with some UTF8 characters. Check that as well.

Comment: this->input->post() doesnt seem to work... doesnt return nothing

Comment: Try monitoring your form with firebug, is the field value being submitted correctly?

Comment: yes the value is being submitted correctly... however in php it cant be assigned in the variable

Comment: in your config file is `$config['global_xss_filtering']` set to `TRUE`? try setting it to `FALSE`